# Volume of a rounded cylinder

Tags: volume, solid-of-revolution

Okay so I have a cylinder with bottom edges that are slightly rounded. How can I calculate the volume of this cylinder? I have come across Pappus' theorem, but I am unsure if that is still valid since the cylinder is only slightly curved at the bottom.

[image: See image of the cylinder here]

Thanks

Comment: I suspect your best bet is actual measurement.  If you have one on you that is empty and you can fill with water, do that, and then pour out into a measuring cup.

Comment: @DanUznanski I'm trying to model it as the volume of a revolution for a maths investigation. So actual measurement isnt what I'm looking for.

Comment: Assuming this is a surface of revolution, you need to model the curve that spins around the $z$-axis to form this shape, and then compute the volume as you would for any surface of revolution by slicing into disks.

Comment: Following what @Ted says, you can also compute the area and centroid of the region described by the model curve and apply Pappus's theorem, to wit, $V=2\pi RA$, where $R$ is the $x$-component of the centroid.